# Python : Calling a function while Popen is still running

Tags: python, subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if "somestring" in line:
        functionCall()
```

In above code snipped, I need to call "functionCall" whenever "somestring" is present in line. However, this causes the subprocess itself to complete. Anyway to accomplish the task I am trying?

Comment: I assume on return from `functionCall()` the subprocess are completed and you don't read the remaining output from `.stdout...`.

Comment: @stovfl That's correct

Comment: Did you need further help, or can this Answer be closed?